# Мультизагрузка фотографий в Django

Tags: django

Есть Django 2.2 и модель поста. Планируется сделать так: У каждого поста должна быть своя галерея с фотографиями. Загружать фотки нужно пачкой за один раз, так же нужно что бы эти фотографии были привязаны к конкретному посту, а точнее к его модели что бы в дальнейшем перебирать эти фотки в шаблонах и т.д. Я даже не представляю как подойти к решению такой задачи. Может быть есть какие ни будь библиотеки для реализации такого функционала?

Comment: В документации [это описано](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Модель поста:

```
class Post(Model):
   ...
```

Модель изображения для поста:

```
class PostImage(Model):

    post = ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="images")
    image = ImageField(upload_to=image_directory_path)
```

Добавлять изображения можно в самом серииализаторе, переопределив метод `create`:

```
class PostSerializer(Serializer):
    ### Есть несколько путей реализации поля `images`
    images = ListField(child=FileField(max_length=100000,
                                       allow_empty_file=False,
                                       use_url=False)
    images = PostImageSerializer(source='images', many=True, read_only=True)

    ...
    def create(self, validated_data):
        post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)
        images = validated_data.pop('images')
        for image in images:
            image = Image.objects.create(post=post, image=image)
        return post
    ...
```

Я не знаю, как вы строите `view`, но с `ModelViewSet` это будет выглядеть так:

```
class Post(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
```

Comment: У меня въюха построена на функциях. А ещё у меня такой вопрос, я весь день ищу информацию по серриализаторам, но все что нашел это АПИ рест фреймворк. Серриализатор который Вы предложили где нужно написать?

Comment: Сериализаторы есть в Django - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/serialization/
в идеале, хранить их в модуле `serializers.py` рядом с `models.py`, `views.py` и т.д.

Но лучше вложите время, изучите документацию DRF - https://www.django-rest-framework.org/#quickstart

Comment: Спасибо большое, обязательно прочту. А views обязательно на классах реализовывать придётся? Или можно как-то в существующей функции post_detail (request, slug) это все реализовать?

Comment: @Uncle_Ragnar, вы используете просто `django`, без `rest framework`, верно?

Comment: Да, все так. Только Django и Pillow....

Comment: И еще пайчарм ругается на сериализатор, говорит в class PostSerializer(Serializer): необходимо добавить ABC...